# Ubuntu: Deleting a partition containing corrupt ubuntu upgrade from other ubuntu partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, upgrade

We have tried to upgrade Ubuntu from v16 to v18, in the course it got corrupted so we have installed a fresh Ubuntu via bootable USB in a parallel partition. We are currently using the fresh installed Ubuntu v18

So question is, is it okay to format other partition with corrupted Ubuntu installation and merge it in fresh installed ubuntu OS partition.

Can formatting corrupted ubuntu installation cause issue while booting?

Answer (score 0):

> So question is, is it okay to format other partition with corrupted Ubuntu installation and merge it in fresh installed ubuntu OS partition.

Yes.

> Can formatting corrupted ubuntu installation cause issue while booting?

Not really. But you can prepare yourself: create a [boot-repair](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) usb and use that to repair your boot if there are any problems. Together with a gparted live and a Ubuntu live tools that are invaluable for an admin.